# OpenCV YAML parser does not recognize "true"/"false" values

Tags: c++, opencv, yaml

OpenCV's YAML parser does not recognize "true"/"false" values.
According to the [YAML definition of bool](https://yaml.org/type/bool.html), these values should be interpreted as boolean values.

Example code:

```
bool b(false);
cv::FileStorage fs("/tmp/test.yaml", cv::FileStorage::READ);
if(!fs["b"].empty())  fs["b"] >> b;
fs.release();
```

"/tmp/test.yaml":

```
b: false
b: False
b: off
b: 0
```

Only when `b:0`, `b` becomes `false`.  Otherwise, `b==true` as the values (`false/False/off`) are translated as an integer value (cf. the [OpenCV source code-persistence.hpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/persistence.hpp#L1122)).

Comment: Did you open an OpenCV issue for this bug?

Comment: @eike The linked definition is not part of the YAML specification and also based on outdated YAML 1.1. YAML 1.2 does define a *bool* tag as part of the JSON schema which *should* be supported by an implementation, but this is not a requirement. OpenCV is free to ignore it. Since their docs show YAML 1.0, which is so old that it is hardly used anywhere anymore, I highly doubt they are actively maintaining this.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is overwriting the behavior of `operator>>` for `bool` by specializing the template.

More concretely:

```
namespace cv
{
// Define a new bool reader in order to accept "true/false"-like values.
void read_bool(const cv::FileNode &node, bool &value, const bool &default_value)
{
  std::string s(static_cast<std::string>(node));
  if(s=="y"||s=="Y"||s=="yes"||s=="Yes"||s=="YES"||s=="true"||s=="True"||s=="TRUE"||s=="on"||s=="On"||s=="ON")
    {value=true; return;}
  if(s=="n"||s=="N"||s=="no"||s=="No"||s=="NO"||s=="false"||s=="False"||s=="FALSE"||s=="off"||s=="Off"||s=="OFF")
    {value=false; return;}
  value= static_cast<int>(node);
}
// Specialize cv::operator>> for bool.
template<> inline void operator >> (const cv::FileNode& n, bool& value)
{
  read_bool(n, value, false);
}
} // cv
```